# Error compiling a package: "configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.0.0"

Tags: package-management, compiling, install-from-source

I am trying to compile a package, which requires gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.0.3. I think I have an older vesion installed on my system. So I downloaded and compiled gstreamer-1.0.4 and it got installed in /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0.

After I did that, I again tried to compile the package but it still gives the same error that I dont have "gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.0.3" .

I also tried to export the path

> "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0"

"whereis gstreamer-1.0" outputs

> gstreamer-1: /usr/lib64/gstreamer-1.0 /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0
>   /usr/libexec/gstreamer-1.0 /usr/share/gstreamer-1.0

Actual Error Message

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking nano version... 0 (release)
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /bin/ld
checking if the linker (/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... /bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /bin/msgmerge
checking for ld used by GCC... /bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for VALGRIND... no
configure: Using GStreamer Base Plug-ins source release as package name
configure: Using Unknown package origin as package origin
configure: Using GST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH = $(top_builddir)/pkgconfig
configure: Using /usr/local/libexec/gst-install-plugins-helper as plugin install helper

configure: *** checking feature: building of plug-ins with external deps ***
configure: building external plug-ins

configure: *** checking feature: building of experimental plug-ins ***
configure: not building experimental plug-ins
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: working c++ compiler found: yes
checking for valgrind... /bin/valgrind
checking for gobject-introspection... yes
checking for gtkdoc-check... /bin/gtkdoc-check
checking for gtkdoc-rebase... /bin/gtkdoc-rebase
checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... /bin/gtkdoc-mkpdf
checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
configure: Looking for Python version >= 2.1
checking for python... /bin/python
checking "/bin/python":... okay
checking local Python configuration... looks good
checking whether to build plugin documentation... no (gtk-doc disabled or not available)
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking xmmintrin.h usability... yes
checking xmmintrin.h presence... yes
checking for xmmintrin.h... yes
checking emmintrin.h usability... yes
checking emmintrin.h presence... yes
checking for emmintrin.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for process.h... no
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint types... stdint.h (shortcircuit)
make use of stdint.h in _stdint.h (assuming C99 compatible system)
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for log2... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking for lrint... yes
checking for lrintf... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 implements __PRETTY_FUNCTION__... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 implements __FUNCTION__... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 implements __func__... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for glib-genmarshal... glib-genmarshal (from pkg-config path)
checking for glib-mkenums... glib-mkenums
checking for GIO... yes
checking for ORC... no
checking for GST... no
configure: No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found
configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.0.0 (GStreamer) found
```

I need help because I am still trying to learn the basics!!
Thank you!!

Comment: is there any error regarding version, and please could you update the complete error log..

Comment: ok, I copied the entire output of the console, I hope that is what you wanted.

Comment: which ubuntu are you using ?

Answer (score 30):

You have to install the *-dev packages in order to compile something which uses/links against some library. I guess `libgstreamer1.0-dev`, `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`  is missing. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

PS: You can check the version of some packages with `apt-cache policy`. Example: `apt-cache policy libgstreamer1.0-dev`